# Parse JSON in Objective-C with SBJSON

Tags: objective-c, json

I just want to parse this JSON string in Objective-C using the SBJSON framework, and retrieve the three units of data:

```
{"x":"197","y":"191","text":"this is a string"}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString * jsonString = @"{\"x\":\"197\",\"y\":\"191\",\"text\":\"this is a string\"}";
SBJSON *jsonParser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary * dictionary = [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString];
NSLog(@"x is %@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"x"]);
[jsonParser release];
```

Comment: also note that [dictionary objectForKey:@"x"] will return an NSNumber, not an integer, hence the use of the %@ format specifier.

Comment: `[dictionary objectForKey:@"x"]` will actually return an `NSString` since the value is quoted in the original JSON data.

Comment: That's a truly ancient version of SBJson. Please do not use it any more!

Comment: ha, That is dedication! feel free to update or include links to new examples or documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
NSString *jsonText = @"...";
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:jsonText];
for (NSString *key in [@"x y text" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) {
  NSLog(@"%@ => %@", key, [dict objectForKey]); 
}
```

Here's something similar for SBJson4Parser:

```
id parser = [SBJson4Parser parserWithBlock:^(id v, BOOL *stop) {
    for (NSString *key in [@"x y text" componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ => %@", key, [v objectForKey]); 
    }
}
allowMultiRoot:NO
unwrapRootArray:NO
errorHandler:^(NSError *err) {
    // handle error here                                 
}];

NSString *jsonText = @"...";
[parser parse: [jsonText UTF8String]];
```

Comment: Is this simple parse possible with SBJson4Parser ?

Comment: @ReneDohan yes, although your code would be quite different. If you want to parse small JSON strings that you already have access to on the local machine you should probably just use NSJSONSerialisation. If you need/want asynchronous parsing, reach for SBJson4Parser.

Comment: But I need also functionality of - (id)proxyForJson , that I really on now and I don't see it in other libraries. Thank you.

Comment: @ReneDohan that makes sense, so I added an example. As you can see it's not what SBJson 4 is best suited at :-)

Comment: So I will stay on 3.1.1 version now , as I see it there is no simple json library that can do what sbjson3 is capable of by simple syntax, I am expecting parser to output dictionary, as I see i can create dictionary in that block but it seems to me be developer unfriendly, proxyForJson functionality is very handy for me I can create complex object data hierarchies and convert them back to json... For me it is best feature together with simple parsing

Comment: That is fine. Version 3.x won't magically stop working just because version 4 is out :-) Version 4 is really taking a slightly different direction, so I renamed all the classes so you can even use both v3 and v4 together in the same app. You might want to do that if you're happy with version 3 in general, but had one or more specific case where version 4 would really shine.

Comment: Ok thanks for library, I was just afraid that version 3 is abandoned and I can run to some problems if it is not maintained and current, I like to use most current stable versions of libraries if possible , because IOS world is moving fast forward...