# Using SBJson, how to retrieve list of strings from array of objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse JSON in Objective-C with SBJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509214/parse-json-in-objective-c-with-sbjson)

I have below JSON Response (String). I want to parse it into an `NSArray` with all the patient names.

```
[{"pat_reg_no":"111181031P1","app_start_time":"10.15","pat_firstname":"Will Smith"},
 {"pat_reg_no":"111181031P2","app_start_time":"11.15","pat_firstname":"Shane Watson"},
 {"pat_reg_no":"111181031P3","app_start_time":"12.15","pat_firstname":"Michael Hussey"},
 {"pat_reg_no":"111181031P1","app_start_time":"10.15","pat_firstname":"Will Smith"}]
```

How do I parse this?

Comment: Please visit [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509214/parse-json-in-objective-c-with-sbjson). Here they talk about the same problem and there is solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below Code.

```
NSString* jsonString;
//jsonString suppose this String has That JSON Response.

SBJSON *parser = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDictionary *jsonResponse = (NSDictionary*)[parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
NSArray *pat_reg_noArray = [jsonResponse valueForKey:@"pat_reg_no"] ;
NSArray *app_start_timeArray= [jsonResponse  valueForKey:@"app_start_time"] ;
NSArray*firstnameArray=[jsonResponse  valueForKey:@"pat_firstname"];
```

I hope It 'll work.

Comment: @divakar you welcome ,so you should up vote my answer..!!!!!.

Comment: This is using an _old_ version of SBJson. The SBJSON class was deprecated years ago. Please use a more recent version :-)  [Disclaimer: I am the author of SBJson]

Comment: @StigBrautaset please suggest me link for the same ..!! thanks

Comment: Current releases can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads

Answer (score 3):

I write a demo for you.

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
id jsonObj = [parser objectWithString:@"[{\"pat_reg_no\":\"111181031P1\",\"app_start_time\":\"10.15\",\"pat_firstname\":\"Will Smith\"},{\"pat_reg_no\":\"111181031P2\",\"app_start_time\":\"11.15\",\"pat_firstname\":\"Shane Watson\"},{\"pat_reg_no\":\"111181031P3\",\"app_start_time\":\"12.15\",\"pat_firstname\":\"Michael Hussey\"},{\"pat_reg_no\":\"111181031P1\",\"app_start_time\":\"10.15\",\"pat_firstname\":\"Will Smith\"}]"];

if ([jsonObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (id obj in jsonObj) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSString *name = [obj objectForKey:@"pat_firstname"];
            NSLog(@"name %@", name);
        }
    }
}
[parser release];
```

Answer (score 1):

The Array which you have posted belongs to someKey, so do the following

```
SBJSON *jsonParser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary * dictionary = [jsonParser objectWithString:YourString];
NSArray * array = [dictionary objectForKey:someKey];
NSMutableArray *nameArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array)
{
    [nameArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"pat_firstname"];
}
NSLog(@"x is %@",nameArray);
[jsonParser release];
```

Hope this will solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSArray* array = [(NSDictionary*)[jsonString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"results"];
```

Comment: must import "JSON.h" and "SBJson.h"

Comment: Why `JSON.h` *and* `SBJson.h`? That doesn't sound right. Depending on the version of the library you're using you should only have to include one of them. [Disclaimer: I am the author of SBJson.]